# Webpack lazy loading: chunk failed to load for dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I have created a Vue.js library using the @vue/cli@4. Within this library I used lazy-loading for some code to reduce the initial bundle size.

In my library's demo area the components work fine and all chunks get loaded.

When importing my library to another Vue.js project (also @vue/cli@4) I get an error when webpack tries to load the chunk:

```
lib.common.js?5698:107 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:8080/js/lib.common.chunk.js)
    at Function.requireEnsure [as e] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lib/dist/lib.common.js:107:26)
    at VueComponent.beforeCreate (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/lib/dist/lib.common.js:8276:25)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1853:57)
    at callHook (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:4213:7)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:4994:5)
    at new VueComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:5144:12)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:3280:10)
    at init (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:3111:45)
    at createComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:5968:9)
    at createElm (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:5915:9)
```